# wordpress external links behaving strangely

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following jQuery code in a Wordpress installation.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script>
//var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

function test() {
    alert("hello from covenant");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.likebtn_container").remove();
    $(".content-column.one_fifth.last_column a").click(function() {
//        test();
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(href);
        $.get(href, function(data, status){
            alert('in get');
            var begin = data.search("<article");
//            var stop = data.search("</article");
//            var begin = data.search('<main id="main"');
            var stop = data.search("</article");
            data = data.substring(begin, stop);
            $("div.content-column.four_fifth").html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });

});

</script>
```

In a two column page, I have a link in the righthand column. When the link is clicked, the "get" function loads the contents into "data", which is then searched in order to extract the html from a section of the document.

When href is a page or post on my wordpress site, everything works fine. I  the "href" alert, then the "get" alert, and then the desired portion of the page loads into the left column, and the link is prevented from opening with "return false".

However, when href is an external site, I see the "href" alert twice, do not see the "get" alert, and then the entire external site replaces the content of my page.

I am stumped by how to get an external link to behave like an internal link in my application.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: On the remote website you don't have `<article` in HTML. May this be your problem. Let me know and I will add the answer.

Comment: That is correct. Here's the corrected segment that I use when testing the external site.
//            var begin = data.search("<article");
//            var stop = data.search("</article");
//            var begin = data.search('<main id="main"');
//            var stop = data.search("</article");
var begin = 10;
var stop = 200;
It never makes it into the "get" routine, however, at least according to the non-execution of the alert("in get") statement.

Comment: So are you still in a problem?

Comment: You can update the main question better.

Comment: Yes. The test() function executes twice, and the alert in get() never executes.

Comment: My website is "http://bahaistudiesinthecovenant.com". The problem is that the code works fine on "http://bahaistudiesinthecovenant.com/2016/07/10/the-concept-of-covenant/". It fails on "http://bahai-covenant.blogspot.com/2016/07/word-god-attracts-believer.html". In other words, it works when the href is to a page on my wordpress installation, and fails when the href is an external webpage.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to wordpress handling remote links differently than local ones.

Comment: Figured it out: same origin policy problem.

Comment: glad you make it.